# How to split my figure (folder directory tree) into two columns in latex as shown in the screenshot?

Tags: tikz-trees, forest, split, directory, folders

[image: ReQuired Figure]

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=12pt, a4paper]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\definecolor{folderborder}{RGB}{110,144,169}
\definecolor{folderbg}{rgb}{0.91, 0.84, 0.42}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{floatrow}
\newlength\Size
\setlength\Size{4pt}
\tikzset{%
  folder/.pic={%
    \filldraw [draw=folderborder, top color=folderbg!50, bottom color=folderbg] (-1.05*\Size,0.2\Size+5pt) rectangle ++(.75*\Size,-0.2\Size-5pt);
    \filldraw [draw=folderborder, top color=folderbg!50, bottom color=folderbg] (-1.15*\Size,-\Size) rectangle (1.15*\Size,\Size);
  },
  file/.pic={%
    \filldraw [draw=folderborder, top color=folderborder!5, bottom color=folderborder!10] (-\Size,.4*\Size+5pt) coordinate (a) |- (\Size,-1.2*\Size) coordinate (b) -- ++(0,1.6*\Size) coordinate (c) -- ++(-5pt,5pt) coordinate (d) -- cycle (d) |- (c) ;
  },
}
\forestset{%
  declare autowrapped toks={pic me}{},
  pic dir tree/.style={%
    for tree={%
      folder,
      font=\ttfamily,
      grow'=0,
    },
    before typesetting nodes={%
      for tree={%
        edge label+/.option={pic me},
      },
    },
  },
  pic me set/.code n args=2{%
    \forestset{%
      #1/.style={%
        inner xsep=2\Size,
        pic me={pic {#2}},
      }
    }
  },
  pic me set={directory}{folder},
  pic me set={file}{file},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  pic dir tree,
  where level=0{}{% folder icons by default; override using file for file icons
    directory,
  },
[
[OpenFOAM,
        [system
                 [\fname{controlDict.sim}{}, file]
                 [\fname{controlDict.moveDyn}{}, file]
                 [\fname{controlDict}{}, file]
                 [\fname{createPathDict.ami}{}, file]
                 [\fname{decomposeParDict}{}, file]
                 [\fname{topoSetDict}{}, file]
                 [\fname{...}{}, file]

        ]
        [Constant
                [polyMesh]
                [\fname{dynamicMeshDict}{}, file]
                [\fname{...}{}, file]
        ]
        [0
               [\fname{pointDisplacement}{}, file]
               [\fname{U}{}, file]
               [\fname{...}{}, file]
        ]

        [MeshFactory
                   [\fname{...}{}, file]
        ]
        [postProcessing]
        [log]
]
[\fname{runMesh.sh}{}, file]
[\fname{runMoveDyn.sh}{}, file]
[\fname{runBatchJob.Job}{}, file]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a pretty involved situation. The solution below crucially relies on Forest's ability to draw only a part of the tree, by setting `draw tree processing order`, and to output multiple TikZ pictures, by modifying `draw tree stage` to call `draw tree` more than once.

Below, we define style `draw part of tree`, which is given two arguments, the starting node and the final node to be drawn; the two nodes are specified as nodewalks from the root. This style is then used in the redefinition of `draw tree stage` to output chunks of the tree.

Further complications arise to draw the continuation dots and arrow. Whenever the last drawn node is not the final node in the tree, `draw part of tree` will call style `to be continued` (and pass the first and the last drawn node  to this style). This style is customizable; below, in calls `dots below`, which needs to know the last drawn node, and `arrow to next tree`, which needs no arguments.

`dots below` takes the `y` coordinate of the last drawn node, and draws the vertical line (followed by vertical dots) for each node with undrawn children; these are the ancestors of the first undrawn node.

`arrow to next tree` draws the arrow, consulting only the current bounding box. It relies on `begin draw` having set the `baseline` to vertically align the tree chunks at the top.

Style `to be continued` is called, from within `draw tree`, after the tree chunk was output (but before the internal `tikzpicture` is closed). To get the edges to undrawn parents (and the vertical dots above these edges) in a tree chunk that is a continuation, the approach is to modify these "undrawn" parent nodes *before* drawing the tree. This happens in style `prepare fake ancestors`, called by `draw part of tree`.

`prepare fake ancestors` eventually calls two customizable styles. `init prepare fake parent` is called in the context of the first drawn node; below, it remembers the `y` coordinate of that node. `prepare fake parent` then puts the undrawn parent a bit above the remembered `y` coordinate — this gets right the edges from the "undrawn" parents to their drawn children. `prepare fake parent` also turns the undrawn parents into coordinate nodes, removes their edges and puts vertical dots above them.

The "undrawn" parents must of course be actually drawn (otherwise Forest would not draw the edges to their children), but to get them drawn, they must appear in `draw tree processing order`.  I have simplified the implementation by requiring that the first argument of `draw part of tree` must walk from the root to the first drawn node ancestor by ancestor. For example, the second invocation of `draw part of tree` below steps on root, "OpenFAM" and "0" nodes.  Things would not work if we stepped directly onto "0", for example by naming it.

As I said, the solution here is quite involved, and understanding it fully will require reading the manual, in particular section 3.4 "Workflow", but I'm of course happy to explain things in more detail if a specific question arises.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\definecolor{folderborder}{RGB}{110,144,169}
\definecolor{folderbg}{rgb}{0.91, 0.84, 0.42}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{floatrow}
\newlength\Size
\setlength\Size{4pt}
\tikzset{%
  folder/.pic={%
    \filldraw [draw=folderborder, top color=folderbg!50, bottom color=folderbg] (-1.05*\Size,0.2\Size+5pt) rectangle ++(.75*\Size,-0.2\Size-5pt);
    \filldraw [draw=folderborder, top color=folderbg!50, bottom color=folderbg] (-1.15*\Size,-\Size) rectangle (1.15*\Size,\Size);
  },
  file/.pic={%
    \filldraw [draw=folderborder, top color=folderborder!5, bottom color=folderborder!10] (-\Size,.4*\Size+5pt) coordinate (a) |- (\Size,-1.2*\Size) coordinate (b) -- ++(0,1.6*\Size) coordinate (c) -- ++(-5pt,5pt) coordinate (d) -- cycle (d) |- (c) ;
  },
}
\forestset{%
  declare autowrapped toks={pic me}{},
  pic dir tree/.style={%
    for tree={%
      folder,
      font=\ttfamily,
      grow'=0,
    },
    before typesetting nodes={%
      for tree={%
        edge label+/.option={pic me},
      },
    },
  },
  pic me set/.code n args=2{%
    \forestset{%
      #1/.style={%
        inner xsep=2\Size,
        pic me={pic {#2}},
      }
    }
  },
  pic me set={directory}{folder},
  pic me set={file}{file},
}
\newcommand\fname[2]{#1}

\forestset{
  arrow to next tree/.code={
    \draw[dashed] (current bounding box.south east) -- ++(1.5em,0);
    \draw[->](current bounding box.south east) ++(0.25em,0) -- ++(1.5em,0) -- (current bounding box.north east) -- ++(1.5em,0);
  },
  dots below/.style={
    for group={#1}{
      tempdima/.option=y,
      for next node={
        for ancestors={
          TeX={%
            \draw([xshift=\forestregister{folder indent}].parent anchor)--([xshift=\forestregister{folder indent}]\forestoption{x},\forestregister{tempdima}) node[anchor=north]{\vdots};
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
  prepare fake ancestors/.style={
    for group={#1}{
      init prepare fake parent,
      prepare fake ancestors',
    },
  },
  prepare fake ancestors'/.style={
    if nodewalk valid={parent}{
      for parent={
        prepare fake parent,
        prepare fake ancestors',
      },
    }{},
  },
  init prepare fake parent/.style={
    tempdima/.option=y,
  },
  prepare fake parent/.style={
    y/.register=tempdima, y+=10pt,
    coordinate, edge label={}, no edge,
    tikz={\node at ()[anchor=south,xshift=\forestregister{folder indent}]{\vdots};},
    typeset node,
  },
  draw part of tree/.style 2 args={
    draw tree processing order/.nodewalk style={
      for nodewalk={#2,tempcounta/.option=id}{},
      #1,
      do until={id()==tempcounta()}{next node},
    },
    for root'={
      post draw tree hook/.style={},
      for group={#2}{
        if nodewalk valid={next node}{
          post draw tree hook/.append style={
            to be continued={#1}{#2},
          },
        }{}
      },
      prepare fake ancestors={#1},
      draw tree,
    },
  },
}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  pic dir tree,
  for descendants={% folder icons by default; override using file for file icons
    directory,
  },
  draw tree method/.append style={post draw tree hook},
  begin draw/.append code={[baseline=(current bounding box.north)]},
  to be continued/.style 2 args={
    dots below={#2},
    arrow to next tree,
  },
  draw tree stage/.style={
    draw part of tree={current}{n=1,n=2,last leaf},
    draw part of tree={current,n=1,n=3}{last leaf},
  },
  [
    [OpenFOAM,
      [system
        [\fname{controlDict.sim}{}, file]
        [\fname{controlDict.moveDyn}{}, file]
        [\fname{controlDict}{}, file]
        [\fname{createPathDict.ami}{}, file]
        [\fname{decomposeParDict}{}, file]
        [\fname{topoSetDict}{}, file]
        [\fname{...}{}, file]
      ]
      [Constant
        [polyMesh]
        [\fname{dynamicMeshDict}{}, file]
        [\fname{...}{}, file]
      ]
      [0
        [\fname{pointDisplacement}{}, file]
        [\fname{U}{}, file]
        [\fname{...}{}, file]
      ]
      [MeshFactory
        [\fname{...}{}, file]
      ]
      [postProcessing]
      [log]
    ]
    [\fname{runMesh.sh}{}, file]
    [\fname{runMoveDyn.sh}{}, file]
    [\fname{runBatchJob.Job}{}, file]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**UPDATE:** In a comment, the OP asks how the split points are determined.  This is done by arguments of `draw part of tree`, which occurs in the redefinition of `draw tree stage` in the preamble of the tree. `draw part of tree` takes two arguments, the first and the last  node to be drawn.  Both nodes are specified by a *nodewalk* (see section 3.8 "Nodewalks" of the manual) starting from the root node.

- In the first invocation of `draw tree stage`, the first argument is `current`. Because the nodewalk is evaluated in the context of the root node, this evaluates to the root node itself.  The second argument is `n=1,n=2,last leaf`: starting at the root, we first go the the first child ("OpenFAM"), then go to the second child of this node ("Constant"), then go to the last leaf (terminal node) of this node ("..." inside "Constant" folder).
- In the second invocation of `draw tree stage`, the first argument is `current,n=1,n=3`. We first step on the current node, i.e. the root; then on its first child ("OpenFAM"), then on the third child of this node ("0"), which thereby becomes the frst drawn node.  The second argument is `last leaf`; as it is evaluated in the context of the root, this is the very last node of the tree ("runBatchJob.Job").

Admittedly, this mode of determining split points is cumbersome, especially because we have to take care to step on the ancestors of the first drawn node (as explained above).  Below, you can find the code (which produces the same result) greatly simplifying the user interface. One simply has to announce the splitting by `draw linear split tree` in the preamble of the tree, and then mark the split points, in the tree itself, by `split here`; the nodes marked by `split here` will start a new chunk. (The last chunk is drawn automatically.)

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\definecolor{folderborder}{RGB}{110,144,169}
\definecolor{folderbg}{rgb}{0.91, 0.84, 0.42}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{floatrow}
\newlength\Size
\setlength\Size{4pt}
\tikzset{%
  folder/.pic={%
    \filldraw [draw=folderborder, top color=folderbg!50, bottom color=folderbg] (-1.05*\Size,0.2\Size+5pt) rectangle ++(.75*\Size,-0.2\Size-5pt);
    \filldraw [draw=folderborder, top color=folderbg!50, bottom color=folderbg] (-1.15*\Size,-\Size) rectangle (1.15*\Size,\Size);
  },
  file/.pic={%
    \filldraw [draw=folderborder, top color=folderborder!5, bottom color=folderborder!10] (-\Size,.4*\Size+5pt) coordinate (a) |- (\Size,-1.2*\Size) coordinate (b) -- ++(0,1.6*\Size) coordinate (c) -- ++(-5pt,5pt) coordinate (d) -- cycle (d) |- (c) ;
  },
}
\forestset{%
  declare autowrapped toks={pic me}{},
  pic dir tree/.style={%
    for tree={%
      folder,
      font=\ttfamily,
      grow'=0,
    },
    before typesetting nodes={%
      for tree={%
        edge label+/.option={pic me},
      },
    },
  },
  pic me set/.code n args=2{%
    \forestset{%
      #1/.style={%
        inner xsep=2\Size,
        pic me={pic {#2}},
      }
    }
  },
  pic me set={directory}{folder},
  pic me set={file}{file},
}
\newcommand\fname[2]{#1}

\forestset{
  arrow to next tree/.code={
    \draw[dashed] (current bounding box.south east) -- ++(1.5em,0);
    \draw[->](current bounding box.south east) ++(0.25em,0) -- ++(1.5em,0) -- (current bounding box.north east) -- ++(1.5em,0);
  },
  dots below/.style={
    for group={#1}{
      tempdima/.option=y,
      for next node={
        for ancestors={
          TeX={%
            \draw([xshift=\forestregister{folder indent}].parent anchor)--([xshift=\forestregister{folder indent}]\forestoption{x},\forestregister{tempdima}) node[anchor=north]{\vdots};
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
  prepare fake ancestors/.style={
    for group={#1}{
      init prepare fake parent,
      prepare fake ancestors',
    },
  },
  prepare fake ancestors'/.style={
    if nodewalk valid={parent}{
      for parent={
        prepare fake parent,
        prepare fake ancestors',
      },
    }{},
  },
  init prepare fake parent/.style={
    tempdima/.option=y,
  },
  prepare fake parent/.style={
    y/.register=tempdima, y+=10pt,
    coordinate, edge label={}, no edge,
    tikz={\node at ()[anchor=south,xshift=\forestregister{folder indent}]{\vdots};},
    typeset node,
  },
  draw part of tree/.style 2 args={
    for nodewalk={#1,tempcounta/.option=id}{},
    for nodewalk={#2,tempcountb/.option=id}{},
    draw@part@of@tree/.process=RR{tempcounta}{tempcountb},
  },
  draw@part@of@tree/.style 2 args={
    draw tree processing order/.nodewalk style={
      id=#1,
      ancestors,
      fake={id=#1},
      do until={id()==#2}{next node},
    },
    for root'={
      post draw tree hook/.style={},
      for id={#2}{
        if nodewalk valid={next node}{
          post draw tree hook/.append style={
            to be continued={id=#1}{id=#2},
          },
        }{}
      },
      prepare fake ancestors={id=#1},
      draw tree,
    },
  },
  declare count register=current first node,
  draw linear split tree/.style={
    draw tree method/.append style={post draw tree hook},
    begin draw/.append code={[baseline=(current bounding box.north)]},
    draw tree stage/.style={},
    for root'={current first node/.option=id},
    before typesetting nodes/.process=Ow{id}{
      draw tree stage/.append style={
        draw part of tree={id/.register=current first node}{root',last leaf},
      },
    },
  },
  split here/.style={
    draw tree stage/.append style/.process=ROw2{current first node}{id}{
      draw part of tree={id=##1}{id=##2,previous node},
    },
    current first node/.option=id,
  },
}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  pic dir tree,
  for descendants={% folder icons by default; override using file for file icons
    directory,
  },
  draw linear split tree,
  to be continued/.style 2 args={
    dots below={#2},
    arrow to next tree,
  },
  [
    [OpenFOAM,
      [system
        [\fname{controlDict.sim}{}, file]
        [\fname{controlDict.moveDyn}{}, file]
        [\fname{controlDict}{}, file]
        [\fname{createPathDict.ami}{}, file]
        [\fname{decomposeParDict}{}, file]
        [\fname{topoSetDict}{}, file]
        [\fname{...}{}, file]
      ]
      [Constant
        [polyMesh]
        [\fname{dynamicMeshDict}{}, file]
        [\fname{...}{}, file]
      ]
      [0, split here
        [\fname{pointDisplacement}{}, file]
        [\fname{U}{}, file]
        [\fname{...}{}, file]
      ]
      [MeshFactory
        [\fname{...}{}, file]
      ]
      [postProcessing]
      [log]
    ]
    [\fname{runMesh.sh}{}, file]
    [\fname{runMoveDyn.sh}{}, file]
    [\fname{runBatchJob.Job}{}, file]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: In the above solution the tree isn't cut automatically and I am not able to understand the node cutting criteria.

-I have to cut my parent tree just below the MeshFactory Folder (Sub-node) instead of the 0 folder (main node).                                                                                         I have shared an image of the exact figure below which I want to split.